# Use a case on a Join without return a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, case

I need to do a SQL request in SQL Server like this:

```
Select *
From Table_A
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table_2 ON Table_2.Val1 = Table_A.Val1 
                      AND (CASE WHEN Table_A.TADT IS NOT NULL AND Table_A.HSDT IS NOT NULL THEN Table_A.TADT >= Table_A.HSDT END)
```

It returns an error

> Incorrect syntax for >=

If I delete the case and directly do :

```
Select *
From Table_A
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table_2 ON Table_2.Val1 = Table_A.Val1 AND Table_A.TADT >= Table_A.HSDT
```

It's ok with this nevertheless I need to do this test in the join only "if".

How can I do this in SQL for a SQL Server database please ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Comment: What is the logic of this case? Join table_2 if only Table_A.TADT IS NOT NULL
                                      AND Table_A.HSDT IS NOT NULL
                                      AND Table_A.TADT >= Table_A.HSDT ?

Answer (score 1):

Just apply boolean logic, no need for a `CASE` expression (which, by definition, does always produce a value):

```
Select *
From Table_A
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table_2 ON Table_2.Val1=Table_A.Val1 And
  ( Table_A.TADT IS NULL OR
    Table_A.HSDT IS NULL OR
    Table_A.TADT >= Table_A.HSDT 
  )
```

Comment: Why do you use 'Or' instead of 'And' ? I juste want to test 'Table_A.TADT >= Table_A.HSDT ' only 'if' Table_A.TADT and Table_A.Hsdt is not null

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni - think it through. If `TADT` is NULL, you don't want to perform any further test. If `HSDT` is NULL, you don't want to perform any further test. Only if both of those tests have been *false* do you want to actually test `TADT > HSDT`. So OR is the right way to combine these tests here. (Of course, SQL Server is free to evaluate the tests in any order, but provided one of the `IS NULL` results is true, it means we don't care what the result of the `>` comparison was)

Comment: It's more complicated. here, i simplify my request in order to explain what i want. I just want to do : Left Join Table2 on Table2.aa = Table3.aa and If table2.bb is not null and table3.cc is not null then table3.bb >= Current_TimeStamp and  table3.cc <= Current_TimeStamp End

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni - still, `CASE` won't be the right tool for the job. You just need to think through the required logic and combine them together with `AND`s, `OR`s and `NOT`s.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using `case` in comparisons, but you can, using a structure like this:

```
ON Table_2.Val1 = Table_A.Val1 AND
    1 = (CASE WHEN Table_A.TADT IS NOT NULL AND Table_A.HSDT IS NOT NULL AND
                   Table_A.TADT >= Table_A.HSDT
              THEN 1
              WHEN Table_A.TADT IS NOT NULL AND Table_A.HSDT IS NOT NULL
              THEN 0
              ELSE 0
          END)
```

If you want the second comparison to be true *only* when the values are not null, then you can simply do:

```
ON Table_2.Val1 = Table_A.Val1 AND Table_A.TADT >= Table_A.HSDT
```

`NULL` values will not pass this.

If you want the comparison to be true only when the second condition is true or both values are `NULL`, then this suffices:

```
ON (Table_2.Val1 = Table_A.Val1 AND
    Table_A.TADT >= Table_A.HSDT OR
    (Table_A.TADT IS NOT NULL AND Table_A.HSDT IS NOT NULL)
   )
```

That is, move the additional check from the `then` to the `when` clauses.